# Setting DOMPDF to be able to locate and render an image

Tags: dompdf, codeigniter-4, html-to-pdf

Bear with me, I am trying to use the library: dompdf to produce a PDF file from my web app developed with codeigniter-4.4. A PDF that should include a png image, But it seems that I am getting something wrong somewhere.

I get the dompdf into the ci4 through composer and I was able to generate a PDF file containing desired content but excluding the png image.

So I checked around and came across many suggested solutions which are as follows:

1. `SetChroot` and `SetBasePath` to tell dompdf where to get your image
2. Use absolutely path in your src not relative path.
3. Set `isRometeEnabled` to true
4. Use `$_SERVER_ROOT` plus the remaining trilling path to your image.
   And Soo on

I have tested all as par my little knowledge with php and ci4. But what I understood so far was that I am not getting the instructions done as directed in the above solutions because in each, I see one or two user saying this work for me.

come to my aid on what should I put inside

```
1. $this->getOption->setChroot()
2. $this->getOption->setBasePath()
3. and in the view file, the IMG tag scr should be what please.
```

My controller code currently:

```
$dompdf->getOptions->setChroot(ROOTPATH)
$dompdf->getOptions->setBasePath(base_url())
$dompdf->loadHtml(view('pdfview'))
$dompdf->setPaper('A4')
$dompdf->render()
$dompdf->stream('pdfname')
```

Image in the View file:

`<IMG src="/hotuna/logo.png">`

hotuna is a folder inside public folder of the normal codeigniter folder structure.

Thanks for your anticipated consideration.

Comment: Try removing the first prepended forward slash '/' on your image URL.